# .NET: Is a List<T> Thread Safe when modifying its items without adding or deleting any?

Tags: c#, .net

There are a lot of questions and answers when it comes to thread safety and lists, but I did not find one answering my question. I know that a List generally is not thread safe and that there are thread safe alternatives in .NET > 4 like ConcurrentBag. A List, however, is thread-safe when it is only being read from.

Still, I would like to know if it is thread-safe to change a list item's field? I am not adding or removing anything from the list, and there is a 1:1 relation between thread and item, so an item will only be accessed by one thread.

Something like this (just an example)

```
class Item
{
    string ErrorMessage;
    int Status;
    List<string> Stringlist;

    public static async Task modifyList()
    {
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>(){new Item(), new Item(), new Item() };

        foreach (Item item in list)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => { item.ErrorMessage = "Some error"; item.Status = -1; item.Stringlist.Add("Some text"); });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This way it's thread-safe - you don't change list.

Comment: Any read-modify-write operation is unsafe when it is done unsynchronized by multiple threads.  Whether it is done on a list or a list item does not matter.

Comment: In an attempt to improve the quality of my questions, I tried to figure out why this question was closed. According to the "Topics to be asked" https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic questions that cover "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" are fine. Thus, a simple question about a concept being thread-safe or not should be perfectly fine, even without any debugging information or even without the sample I provided as an illustration. Suggestions on how to better ask such a question are highly appreciated.

Comment: @Aileron79 No one can tell you if code not shown will work properly in a multithreaded environment.  Saying that someone ought to be able to tell you if your code is correct without seeing is makes no sense.  Someone could guess at how you implemented it and whether it was correct or not, but SO is not designed for questions where people have to guess at the answer.  That someone told you your code was safe *when they have no idea* doesn't mean it actually is.  Instead they just gave you a false sense of security.  Thinking something is correct when it's not is way worse than not knowing.

Comment: That I do understand. Still I believe I have provided enough information by describing the environmental conditions to answer this question reliably. I don't have any working code yet, that is why I asked the question. @Damien_The_Unbeliever provided not only a "yes" anwer but also explained that a list only contains references. This is an answer I can base a decision on, and this is perfectly what I expected. How else should I have phrased my question to get exactly that answer? Just asking because I want to do it the right way next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Item` doesn't know that (at least one of) its references has been stored in a list. And the list just contains references, not the objects themselves.

By the time you're using the `item` variable, it contains a reference to an `Item` and has no knowledge that the reference was copied from a `List`.

So at the point at which you do `item.ErrorMessage = <something>`, you have a reference and an object, neither of which have any knowledge that a `List` has been involved in reaching that point.

That access is as thread safe as the `Item` object is and your ability to reason about how threads interact with its `ErrorMessage` property.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed to know. Don't really understand why the question has been closed with "This question needs debugging details", there is nothing I need to debug! This just was question about a concept, I just wanted a yes or no answer like the one you provided.